# Run NPM custom script that depends on the server being on

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run an npm script that needs the server to be up for the duration the script is being run.

My script is like this

```
"scripts" :{ "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js"}
```

That is my basic script to start my server which works fine. However,
I have a script within my node project called `get_data.js` that I will use to collect data and save to a database (`npm run save_data`). I want the server to be stopped when `get_data.js` finishes as I am just interested in getting data.

```
    "scripts" :{ 
        "start": "tsc && node dist/app.js", 
        "save_data": "tsc && node dist/get_data.js"
    }
```

Obviously my `save_data` script is not right. Any ideas or recommendation what I can do?

Comment: I would add pm2, then a postinstall script that inits a `pm2 start "npm run start:app"`, then change `start` to `start:app`, and add one for `start` which is `pm2 start all` then have `"save_data": "pm2 stop all && tsc && node dist/get_data.js"` instead, basically place pm2 in front so you can kill the start when running the other script

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting your question but i think what you want is `process.exit(0);`
At the end of "get_data.js" or whenever youve determined that you want the process to end in your script.

(Although i should note that get_data.js should run its course and end itself unless there is something in your code that is preventing this.)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `save_data` inside `start`:

```js
"start": "tsc && node dist/app.js && npm run save_data"
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not want `save_data` to run when the server is operating on normal condition through `npm start`. I want `save_data` to run its course just like any other scripts like `npm lint` and `npm test`.